# How to select column values based on a greater than condition in row values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

I want to select columns from a data frame if any of the values in the column is greater than 3.

In this `mtcars` example, this criterion will drop `vs` and `am`, as there is no value greater than 3
in those columns.

```
                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a logical vector by comparing the dataframe with 3 and then take sum of columns using `colSums` and select only those columns which has at least one value greater than 3 in it.

```
mtcars[colSums(mtcars > 3) > 0]

#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44    3    1
#....
```

---

Variation using `sapply`

```
mtcars[sapply(mtcars, function(x) any(x > 3))]
```

Comment: oops sorry, I noticed the data what I have is matrix, and if I apply this its not working.. But if I do this  dataf <- as.data.frame(matrix) and then apply on dataf it works... Is there any other functions I can directly apply on Matrix?

Comment: @Vlad In case of matrix you just need to add an additional comma to subset columns. For example, `mat <- as.matrix(mtcars);
mat[,colSums(mat > 3) > 0]
`

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr`:

```
mtcars[,purrr::map_lgl(mtcars,~any(.x>3))]
```

Output(truncated):

```
   #                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec gear carb
   # Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46    4    4
   # Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02    4    4
   # Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61    4    1
   # Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44    3    1
   # Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02    3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
## find max val for each column
maxcolval <- apply(mtcars,MARGIN=2,FUN=max)
## select columns
mtcars[maxcolval>3]
```

does what you want. If you want a tidyverse solution (since you have `dplyr` in the tags),

```
library(dplyr) 
mtcars %>% select_if(~max(.)>3)
```